# What is the value of a NULL address location?

Tags: c, null

Why does this code print 4 as the output?

Please also provide some details to help me to understand this type of behaviour better.

```
int main(){ 
     int *p=NULL;
     printf("%d" ,p+1);
     return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting *undefined behavior*. It is only valid to add an integer to a pointer if the pointer points to an element of an array or one beyond the end of an array and result of moving the pointer by the number of positions denoted by the integer also points to an element of the same array, or one beyond the end. (A non-array object can be treated as the only element of a one element array for these purposes.)

A null pointer doesn't point at an element of an array so you can't add one to it. (In C++ it is explicitly allowed to add 0 to a null pointer value and get a null pointer value as the result. (See [this blog entry](http://www.drdobbs.com/blogs/cpp/240001022) by Andrew Koenig at Dr. Dobb's.)

You get further *undefined behavior* by passing a pointer value to `printf` where the corresponding format specifier is `%d` which expects and `int`. `%p` is the correct format specifier for `void*`, you need an explicit cast if you want to print the pointer as an `int` with `%d`.

If your program has *undefined behavior* then there are no guarantees about anything that might happen. You certainly can't infer anything about the language from observing the results and it is arguable what the merit there is trying to infer properties of the implementation from such behaviour as, without further evidence in the form of observable results from programs which don't have *undefined behavior* or guarantees from the compiler vendor, you won't know what circumstances might cause the observed behavior to change.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but while your answer is technically correct, it doesn't actually explain the result, which is reproducible in most environments.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: Thanks. I've now added some further clarification.

Answer (score 9):

You're setting a pointer to 0 (NULL) and then adding 1 to it; then you're converting the result to an `int` and printing the result. The key piece of knowledge you need here is that when you increment (add 1 to) a pointer, you actually add the size of the pointed-to object -- an `int` pointer is advanced to point to the *next* `int`. Since `int` is (apparently) 4 bytes on your platform, `p` is incremented to point to an address 4 bytes past where it starts.

Comment: does pointing a pointer to NULL really make it point to the starting location in the address map ?? and incrementing it makes it to the next address location ?? Address are always printed in some hex conversion to int when we use %d as a specifier so when it outputs just 4 i became doubtful

Comment: Pointers are only printed in hexadecimal if something chooses to print them that way; here you're using the decimal `int` conversion in `printf()`, so that's how your pointer is displayed. Although the other answers mentioning undefined behavior are technically correct, the truth is indeed that on many systems, a pointer is simply a numeric address in memory, and the behavior really is as simple as this.

Answer (score 3):

Size of the `int` in C is (typically) 4 bytes. So incrementing a pointer by one unit means incrementing it's value by `sizeof(int)`.

Also, you aren't printing the value of which pointer is directing (as this would certainly crash your program) but the value of the pointer itself. You should definitely take a look at any pointers tutorial in C (or in general).

Comment: thanks a lot , does it really point to the first address location when we point to NULL ??

Comment: As Ernest said, pointers are generally just direct addresses to memory, so, indeed, it would point to the first address location. This memory region is however inaccessible to any program. The memory used by programs is allocated by operating systems and generally it will result in crash if you try to read/write memory beyond these boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that `p + 1` is an invalid pointer (i.e., a pointer that is neither `NULL` nor it points to a valid object / one past the array object) and any use of it is undefined behavior.

```
printf("%d" ,p+1);
```

or (more correct):

```
printf("%p", (void *) (p + 1));
```

is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the address of p, not the value of what is stored AT address p. p = NULL sets p to zero. Since it is a pointer to an integer, incrementing it by one actually increments the pointer by the size of an integer, typically 4 or 8 bytes.

Attempting to print what is stored at address zero (or even 4) via *p will typically terminate your program on most systems since that area of memory is protected.